# Calculating the offset between two columns in a dataframe but ignoring some of the outliers in one of those

Tags: r, dataframe, offset

I have a dataeframe with two columns, one of which is the baseline (baseline_CO2) I have calculated using a previous set of data and the other is a set of data I believe to be offset with respect to this baseline value.

I want to quantify this offset and calculate it's value in order to correct my original data (CO2_LICOR). In order to do this accurately I need to be able to remove some of the outlier peak values in this offset calculation for the LICOR_CO2 data, say all values over 350.

Can anyone help?

The dataframe looks like the following:

[image]

Comment: Please include data as code, not as a screenshot. Otherwise you're asking anyone who wants to help to either manually type in some of your data, or to try out some code without any way to test that it actually works on your data. Often easiest to include the output of `dput(head(YOUR_TABLE, REPRESENTATIVE_NUMBER_OF_ROWS))` in the body of your question.

Comment: Are you looking to create a column showing the difference between those two columns? `YOUR_DATAFRAME$offset = YOUR_DATAFRAME$baseline_CO2 - YOUR_DATAFRAME$CO2_LICOR` would add that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare the two rows then you can use the approach Jon Spring suggested.

```
df$offset <- df$baseline_CO2 - df$CO2_LICOR
```

If you want to filter these values then something like

```
df_filtered <- df[df$CO2_LICOR < 350]
```